# When a window is over Dock (at NSScreenSaverWindowLevel for eg) why Dock still reacts to mouse movements? How to disable it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow

I encountered an interesting problem. A window floats over Dock at `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel` or similar level and if you mouse over that window, the Dock still reacts to the mouse (zooms or shows app titles) even though it is covered by the window. I need to disable it since my window is partially transparent. I believe it should be possible, some apps do it and standard screen capture tool also somehow disables Dock. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give an example of the such app?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by sending NSApp a setPresentationOptions: message.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000012-SW96

Comment: That works as long as your app is the active app which unfortunately is not the case for me.

Comment: Technically your answer is correct the way the original question was posed so you deserve the bounty. Still, if anyone knows how to stop the Dock from seeing and reacting to mouse events while it's covered by a window, even when the covering application is not the active one, I'd love to know.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how setPresentationOptions: can help here. I do not want to hide the Dock, I want it to simply not react to mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without blocking the dock from receiving event taps messages. However, if you want to do so you should look up the Events Taps API.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, James. Mac OS X APIs are so extensive, I never even heard about Events Taps.